# Django Upload 'filename' error

Tags: python, django, csv

The code is simply to upload CVS file and convert data to a LIST.

When users upload a csv file, the filename individual users use is not enforced. I will like to be able to work with any filename users uses for the csv file.

I am getting this error:

> File "views.py", line 35, in upload_file
>       phone_list = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['phonelistfile'])
>
> File "views.py", line 17, in handle_uploaded_file
>       with open(settings.MEDIA_URL+'documents/'+str(filename),'wb') as destination:
>
> NameError: name '**filename**' is not defined

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Upload
from .forms import UploadFileForm 
import csv
import io

# Imaginary function to handle an uploaded file.
#from somewhere import handle_uploaded_file

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open(settings.MEDIA_URL+'documents/'+str(filename),'wb') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
        destination.close()
    #csvfile = f
    csvfile = io.TextIOWrapper(f) # Python 3 Only
    #dialect = csv.sniffer().sniff(codecs.EncodedFile(csvfile, "utf-8").read(1024))
    dialect = csv.sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024), delimiter=";,")
    #csvfile.open()
    csvfile.seek(0)
    #csvreader = csv.reader(codecs.EncodedFile(csvfile, "utf-8"), delimiter=',', dialect=dialect)
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
    return list(csvreader)

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            phone_list = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['phonelistfile'])
            upload_phone_list = Upload()
            upload_phone_list.name = request.name
            upload_phone_list.phonelistfile = request.FILES['file'].file
            upload_phone_list.phonelist = phone_list
            #form.save()
            upload_phone_list.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
#from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Upload(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phonelistfile = models.FileField("phonelistfile", upload_to="media/%Y/%m/%d/")
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)
    phonelist = ArrayField(models.TextField())
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Upload
from django.forms import ModelForm

# FileUpload form class.
class UploadFileForm(ModelForm):
    #name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    #phonelistfile = forms.FileField("phonelistfile", allow_empty_file=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ('name', 'phonelistfile')
```

**Answered:**
I have been able to find the answer. Now, I can  get the filename of the CSV file uploaded by users by adding the code below; thereby collapsing the two functions in views.py into one using:

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            fil = request.FILES['phonelistfile']
            with open('f', 'wb+') as destination:
                for chunk in fil.chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
                    destination.close()
            csvfile = io.TextIOWrapper(open('f', 'rb')) # Python 3 Only
            #Do something with he file....
```

This does the trick.... - fil = request.FILES['phonelistfile']

Answer (score 1):

In the following line, you never define what `filename` is:

```
with open(settings.MEDIA_URL+'documents/'+str(filename),'wb') as destination:
```

Django has no idea what that is. You need to set it as a value somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Jade. I agree. But how do I write the code in such a way that the filename is not explicitly stated, since my users can use any name for their csv file for upload.

Comment: @Divino I'm assuming the `f` variable passed into your function is the file? If yes, instead of `str(filename)`, you can do `str(f.name)`.

Comment: @Jade,  I will try that.

Comment: I have been able to find the answer. By collapsing the two functions in views.py into one using: